# Create / publish a node via sms

Tags: nodes

I have successfully installed sms framework module and configured with [envaya](http://drupal.org/project/sms_envaya) gateway. I have [support ticket](http://drupal.org/project/support) module. I need to allow the users to create ticket (node:support ticket) via sms. Could you please guide me how to accomplished the same.

Comment: What should I use as a server url in envaya android app? and what should go into the password field? Should I put my drupal website admin password?

Answer (score 0):

Normally the SMS gateway will ping a URL on your site with the relevant details from the SMS, e.g appended as a GET querystring.

I've done this before with [hook_menu](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) and a custom callback to listen for the SMS details.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu
 */
function MYMODULE_menu(){
  $items = array();  
  $items['api/sms'] = array(
    'title' => 'SMS listener', 
    'page callback' => 'mymodule_sms_incoming_process', 
    'access arguments' => array('access content'), 
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );

  return $items;

}

/**
 * SMS listener
 * Processing incoming SMS messages
 */
function mymodule_sms_incoming_process(){
  /* Do stuff with SMS parameters 
   * Make sure to sanitize any $_GET vars with filter_xss etc..
   */
  if (!isset($_GET['code']) { return FALSE }
}
```

Comment: how should I create a node? Should I do it via my modules or actions? does sms framework support such actions?

Comment: how would `access arguments` permission works with sms gateway because gateway is anonymous right? could you please explain..